# Opening a new instance of a OneNote notebook via Windows Batch Commands?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, microsoft-onenote

I'm attempting to use a batch file to open up a OneNote notebook .url shortcut, however, the notebook always ends up opening in the existing OneNote instance, replacing the existing view in the instance.

So far, I've been using the following in my batch file to open my OneNote notebooks:

```
@echo off
start "NotebookName.url" "NotebookPATH"
```

How do I open up the specified OneNote Notebook in a new instance of OneNote via batch commands?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE" /hyperlink "onenote:///pathToYour\NotebookName.url"
```

Comment: Error: We couldn't find a notebook at "urlPATH.url". A notebook usually has a table of contents file (*.onetoc or *.onetoc2).

Comment: Interesting. It worked for me. I didn't post until I verified.

Comment: If you have spaces in your path, maybe try inserting the %20 char. I tested this even pointing to a specific page in a notebook and it works.

Comment: Also, if you want the actual full URL for a Notebook, right-click on the notebook and select "Copy link to notebook" and paste that into your batch to see if it helps.